# Xamarin: Context Action Selected Item Background Color

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile

I have a ListView and a custom cell inside it. I added the context Menu and it works fine. The only problem is that when I long press an item in the list the selected item will have a white background on Android which is not visible so the user won't be able to see which item they are selecting. is there anay way to change that?

Comment: Please edit your post and show the xaml.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the color property directly on Android.

1.add the following colors in file `colors.xml`

```
<color name="ListViewSelected">#96BCE3</color>
<color name="ListViewHighlighted">#E39696</color>
```

2.add the following properties in file `styles.xml`

```
  <item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
  <item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewHighlighted</item>
  <item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
  <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
  <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
```

And my whole `styles.xml` is as follows:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>

   

      <item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
      <item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewHighlighted</item>
      <item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
      <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
      <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
      
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```